# Cookiebot Cookie Consent Script

Tags: javascript, angular, cookies, zoho

I am adding ZohosalesIQ to the CookieBot Prior Consent widget on w WP install.

This script given by zoho is

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-cookieconsent="statistics">
    var $zoho = [];
    var $zoho = $zoho || {};
    $zoho.salesiq = $zoho.salesiq || {
        widgetcode: "1c636a8a8d8e3410b7e579760898b7768f3cb213adb21970788a3891735df801800b6e4a1385c37b0f792b9ee54ce",
        values: {},
        ready: function() {}
    };
    var d = document;
    s = d.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.id = "zsiqscript";
    s.defer = true;
    s.src = "https://salesiq.zoho.eu/widget";
    t = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    t.parentNode.insertBefore(s, t);
    d.write("<div id='zsiqwidget'></div>");
</script>
```

I am supposed to be adding `<script type="text/plain" data-cookieconsent="statistics">`

to the script tag to enable prior consent on cookies created by this script however, when I add this it breaks and fails to load.

Console is empty but the page renders as a white page after pre-load.  When I add the code with the jaavscript type tag, it works fine.

I've tried popping itto a call back function but no joy :(
Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 2):

If the script tag is using the deprecated JavaScript function “document.write” it might cause the problem you have described above because using this function the script is loaded synchronously and it will then clear the window content (generates blank page).

To prevent this issue please make sure that the script is loaded asynchronously since the Cookiebot triggers all scripts asynchronously (i.e. to wait for the visitor’s consent) in order to work properly.

You need rewrite it to use a different approach e.g. “document.write = function(node) {document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(‘beforeend’, node);}”